# Annotation of cumulative sums of fields in queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a model which records data from when a user has watched a video:

```
class VideoViewed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

From the queryset I would like to have each object in the queryset store a value which is a cumulative sum of total videos viewed by that specific user up until this point in time.

Currently I have this annotation:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
    user_views_cumsum=Window(Sum('video'),
                             order_by=F('date_time').asc()))\
    .values('user', 'video', 'date_time', 'id', 'user_views_cumsum').order_by('date_time', 'user_views_cumsum')
```

Which I want to give the Queryset:

```
<QuerySet [

{'user': 2, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 5, 'user_views_cumsum': 1}, 
{'user': 2, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 6, 'user_views_cumsum': 2}, 
{'user': 4, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 7, 'user_views_cumsum': 1},
{'user': 2, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 8, 'user_views_cumsum': 3},
{'user': 2, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 9, 'user_views_cumsum': 4}, 
{'user': 4, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 10, 'user_views_cumsum': 2}

]>
```

But is giving me the cumsum of the videos id so it looks like this:

```
<QuerySet [

{'user': 2, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 5, 'user_views_cumsum': 13}, 
{'user': 2, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 6, 'user_views_cumsum': 26}, 
{'user': 4, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 7, 'user_views_cumsum': 39},
{'user': 2, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 8, 'user_views_cumsum': 52},
{'user': 2, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 9, 'user_views_cumsum': 65}, 
{'user': 4, 'video': 13, 'date_time': datetime, 'id': 10, 'user_views_cumsum': 78}

]>
```

There are 2 issues. I need to separate the `user_views_cumsum` to only be a cumsum of *each user's video views* and I need it add the *cumsum* of each user's video views instead of the `id`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Count()` instead of `Sum()` so every viewing will be counted only once.

As you probably know the way relational databases store this type of data is using foreign keys. When calling `Sum('video')` you are asking the sum of the column named `video`, which contains the `id` of the video. This is why you are getting the sum of the ids. However you do not really care about the value of any column, so you can use `count`.

Comment: I feel like such a dummy. I was using `Count()` at first and went to `Sum()`. I don't know a lot about Relational Databases as I haven't been doing this *that long* and I learn things as they are needed - time to learn more about them. Now about the other issue. Do you have a suggestion how to only `Count()` each user's video view? I could probably use a loop here but it seems like Django would have a method for something like this. Is there a way to do this in Django w/out looping over the QS?

Comment: You could use `.filter` before you count

Comment: I have been working on this all morning and cannot get it to filter for each user. How would I go about this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. You want to group by `user` and `movie`? In that case you have to do `.values('user','movie') followed by a group by `pk`. If you mean something else you will need to describe it more clearly

Comment: The cumsum is adding all users views up. I cannot get it to add up distinct users. e.g. `User 2` should have a `user_views_cumsum: 4` in the example above

Comment: It doesn't. I have tried a million different ways. Currently I have it like this: ```        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            user_views_cumsum=Window(Count('pk'), order_by=F('date_time').asc())).values(
            'user', 'video', 'date_time', 'id', 'user_views_cumsum').order_by('date_time', 'user_views_cumsum')``` and it doesn't work. Also made other posts but no one responded so I took them down.

Comment: You need to put `values` before `annotate`

Comment: I have tried that too :) This: `        queryset = queryset.values(
            'user', 'video', 'date_time', 'id').annotate(
            user_views_cumsum=Window(Count('pk'), order_by=F('date_time').asc())).order_by(
            'date_time', 'user_views_cumsum')` still doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208373/discussion-between-mousetail-and-david-alford).